# How to make Anki repeat questions more frequently?

Tags: anki

My Anki configuration suggests that I repeat some card in `<10m`, `1.5mo`, `4.2mo` and `9.4mo`

[image]

Can I make time to grow in more "dense" manner?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have been using your deck for a very very long time and know all the material, it sounds as if the configuration for your deck has somehow got messed up. To reset the configuration, use the `Decks` tab to find the deck that you want to reset. Click on the <kbd>Options</kbd> button at the bottom of the screen. A new screen will appear. Click the <kbd>Restore defaults</kbd> button at the bottom of the new screen.

Please note that there is a specific group of options associated with each deck. You will see the Options Group at the top of the screen that appears when you first press the Options button. When you reset the options to the default settings, that will also reset the options for every deck that uses the particular options group. If you don't want that to happen, use the <kbd>Manage ...</kbd> button to create a new options group for your deck, and set that options group to the default settings.

Comment: Yes, but how to make it to feed knowledge slower?

Comment: @Dims It isn't clear what you mean by "feed knowledge slower". Perhaps you need to edit your question. At the moment you appear to be asking for the "knowledge feed" to be more dense ... i.e., faster.